# Print percent memory and CPU for all processes cumulative on linux

Tags: linux, memory, cpu-usage, pid

Does printing %MEM and %CPU for **Process ID 1** give the %CPU and %MEM for all processes across all users on that linux box?

If not, what is the best alternative? I assume that it's possible to sum the %MEM and %CPU across all the processes generated from `top` or `ps`, is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: Also look at tools like htop which provide nice APIs for data.

Answer (score 0):

Use /proc for getting raw data. Here's an intro http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8381